# Default site when composing a query on SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is it possible to set a site as default when composing/forking a SEDE query? It always defaults to Stack Overflow and the user is required to change sites before running the query.

> [image]

My intention is to drive folks from a specific site into a query that runs directly for that site without the need of swapping sites, thus having to provide instructions for people who don't know SEDE.

I've tried researching into existing queries and checked the database schema. Donnow, but looks like the only possibility would be a URL parameter `&site=SITE_ID`...

I've found the following related questions but there's no hint about this issue:

- [Can we change the SEDE workflow a little?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52087/can-we-change-the-sede-workflow-a-little)
- [Why does Compose Query default to Programmers SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81167/why-does-compose-query-default-to-programmers-se)

Comment: "It always defaults to Stack Overflow" - This isn't quite true, can you explain in a little more detail? You do have to be logged in for it to remember your preference, though.

Comment: But I agree that there's a more general problem of sites "having" queries (even though they're all the same set of queries), instead of queries having site preferences.

Comment: If I open a [given query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks) the site is set as shown in the snapshot (just added to the question + the intention). . . . But, is it a matter of remembering a preference? @Tim

Comment: Ah, you just need to have the right site name in the URL. For example, [linking the query like this](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks) will have it run on WordPress by default.

Comment: Oh, sweet! What about `pt.stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: It's just `pt` in the URL [in that case](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks) (which isn't exactly correct...hm, but I don't think anything's broken by it)

Comment: Oh, I swear I tried that but of course I didn't :/ Nice, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Last query: this `http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntumeta` and this `http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.askubuntu` work, but I can't find the URL to Meta.PT.SO...

Comment: Hm, it's `ptme`, which is definitely wrong. I'll see if that can be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

As [shown by Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238590/default-site-when-composing-a-query-on-sede?noredirect=1#comment781892_238590), it's a matter of adding the site name (*.stackexchange.com) to the URL, like `wordpress` or `pt` (pt.stackoverflow.com):

```
http://data.stackexchange.com/SITE_NAME/query/ID/SLUG
```

Playing with SEDE **and** paying attention to the URLs, this doubt is at plain sight: changing sites shows up the desired URL.